# How to prevent continuous clicks on the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent continuous clicks on the button `.toggler`. When I click on it div is toggling properly, but if I click on it continuously many times div toggles many times until all the click events have not been completed.

The expectation is that if I click the button, its click event should be off until the div has not been toggled properly. After that its click should be on.

Click the button continuously many times to see the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.main-div').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-div {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="toggler">Toggle</button>
<div class="main-div"></div>
```

The jQuery code I have tried is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var thisEement = $(this);
    thisEement.off('click');
    $('.main-div').slideToggle('slow', function(){
      thisEement.on('click');
    });
  });
});
```

But that does not work as expected.

Any help would be appreciated <3.

Comment: `on('click');` does not put the event callback back on, the method expects a second argument, the event callback function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `slideToggle` has a callback function which is invoked when the operation is completed. So, you can introduce a new boolean variable that will be set to `false` when the operation starts and changed back to `true` when the toggle is completed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flag = false;
    $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!flag){
          flag = true;
          $('.main-div').slideToggle( "slow", function() {
             flag = false;
          });
        }
        
    });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;}
.main-div {width: 80%; float: right; height: 200px; background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="toggler">Toggle</button>
<div class="main-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault
    $(".toggler").prop('disabled', true); // disable first
    $('.main-div').slideToggle("slow", function() { // when slidetoggle ends
      $(".toggler").prop('disabled', false); // enable button again.
    });
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5n39xx8c/1/)

Hope helps,

Comment: I'd replace prop() with data(), but that's only to use the right tool. Both work.

Comment: Ahh nevermind! I see! Didn't think of using the html attribute to do the heavy lifting, nice catch.

Comment: Just an example, important thing is `slideTogge("","",function(){});` here :) @RohitSharma

Answer (score 2):

Just use a boolean that will toggle when the slide starts and stops.

```
var inMotion = false;

$('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (inMotion == false) {
    inMotion = true;
    $('.main-div').slideToggle('slow', function() {
      inMotion = false;
    });
  }
});
```

When the `slideToggle()` function finishes, that callback will run. The callback will set the boolean to false, allowing it to fire again.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#togglerButton").attr("disabled", "true");
    $('.main-div').slideToggle('slow', function() {
      $("#togglerButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-div {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="toggler" id="togglerButton">Toggle</button>
<div class="main-div"></div>
```

You can also do this by using event object pass to the click event. you can get count for number of time the click event performed. based on which you can set condition in javascript code and prevent multiple clicks like code given below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
    if (!event.originalEvent.detail || event.originalEvent.detail == 1) {
      $('.main-div').slideToggle('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the disabled attribute on click then remove it once the animation completes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.main-div').slideToggle('slow', function(){
           $('.toggler').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;}
.main-div {width: 80%; float: right; height: 200px; background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="toggler">Toggle</button>
<div class="main-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply filter out the element while it's being animated and thus never queue up multiple toggles on it:

```
$('.main-div').not(':animated').slideToggle('slow');
```

No point in keeping track of this state yourself in some boolean when jQuery does it for you and lets you write functionally!

Full code (your original example modified):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.main-div').not(':animated').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

FYI, your attempt would've worked if you properly re-bound the event handler function, but this is a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var res = false;
    $('.toggler').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!res){
          res = true;
          $('.main-div').slideToggle( "slow", function() {
             res = false;
          });
        }
        
    });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;}
.main-div {width: 80%; float: right; height: 200px; background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="toggler">Toggle</button>
<div class="main-div"></div>
```